# Non-flowering chives

Tags: herbs, chives

My chives are doing well, strong and disease free. But they are not flowering! Could mine be a late flowering variety? Is there such a thing? Or maybe a non-flowering variety? Thanks.

Comment: For easier identification, we could help with a picture of your plant.

Comment: How long have you had them? and what part of the world are you in? Have you cut them for use at all?

Answer (score 4):

I live in a pretty far northern climate, and decided I hated the natural prairie grass landscaping that came with my house. Traditional chives and "Chinese/garlic" chives now dominate the front of my house.

It is now July, and the traditional chives have been blooming round purple flowers since mid-June.

[image: Chives in bloom]

The flatter-leaved, "garlic" chives generally don't flower until late August and September for me, with multiple, delicate-looking white flowers.

[image: garlic chives]

If your chives are more flat-leaved with a bit of a garlicky taste to them, then they probably are the later-blooming variety.